# Post test in adonisjs

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, adonis.js

I'm trying to test a POST request in AdonisJS 5. In AdonisJS 4, you send parameters in this way:

`client.post('posts').send({ title: 'Adonis 101', body: 'Post content'})`

https://legacy.adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/api-tests

However, it seems that it is no longer that way and I haven't found anything useful in the documentation.

I tried using the `send` method, but it's not accepting the expected parameters now

Answer (score 0):

You are using legacy docs, [here](https://docs.adonisjs.com/) is an actual doc.
And by [the docs](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/request), you should use `post` like this:

```
Route.post('/', async ({ request }) => {
  request.body()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue, luckily I found a piece of code where there is the answer:

```
client.post('/posts').json({id: 1, name:"something"})
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Which version of `adonis.js` does this apply to? It looks to me like you mixed up the functions.

Comment: Adonisjs 5.9. This is more explicitly @japa/runner that is used for tests in adonis.